# How to use driver instance in selenium Page Objects?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

In the Selenium PageObjects I am not instantiating any web driver instance and coding as below

```
@FindBy(id = "userID")
WebElementFacade txtusername;
```

I am trying to implement below code into the Selenium Page Object Function.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.linkText("MainMenu"));
action.moveToElement(mainMenu).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("submenuxpath"))).click().build().perform();
```

Can anyone please suggest me that how can i use webdriver instance in above code while working in the Page objects model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the `driver` instance in parent class that all the page objects inherit from.

```
public abstract class AbstractPage {
    protected WebDriver driver;

    protected AbstractPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}

public class ExamplePage extends AbstractPage {
    @FindBy(id = "userID")
    WebElementFacade txtusername;

    public ExamplePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.linkText("MainMenu"));
        action.moveToElement(mainMenu).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("submenuxpath"))).click().build().perform();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways.

**The first way:** you can create getter for your webdriver instance in a class where it's created and use it.

**The second way:** You can inherit a class where you create an instance of webdriver and again, use the driver.

As for me I created a base class where my webdriver is initialized and where the most useful methods are placed (like wait for element, navigate to a page, etc.). And inheriting this class allows all my page objects to have a bunch of very useful features. Each of my PageObjects use webdriver instance of the base class if it's needed.